# How to open activity from push notification and ignore the previous state of application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, push-notification

I am working on an android application. It receives a push notification . I want to open an activity P when user opens the notification.

My application has the following hierarchy of activities:

1. Main Activity (M) , which creates three fragments(F1, F2, F3).
2. F3 has one more fragment inside it (F31). F31 has a listview which displays some list of videos . User can play any video form here.
3. When user clicks any video from F31 , it creates and activity P, for playing the video.

Now when i receive the push notification and open it, i want to open the activity P . But I also want that when activity P is launched and user presses back , then it should go to F31 . Because the parent of P is F31.

My application can be in any state when user opens the push notification . I mean user can be in F1 or F2 or F3 . But when user open the push notification it should launch the activity P and on back press it should go to F31 .
It should ignore the previous state of the application.

I can launch the Activity P from Push Notification , But i am not sure how to guarantee that on back press it will land on F31.

Please suggest how should i proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this on the activity P:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, M.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "goToF31");
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

And in activity F's first thing inside `onCreate`:

```
    String signal = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

    if (signal.equals("goToF31")) {

        // open the F31 fragment
        F31 f31 = new F31();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, f31).commit(); 
    }
```

The logic is put an intent for when the suer clicks the back button inside the video activity that opens the activity F and the fragment F31.
This might work, but to feel right you have to put the animation that makes it look like it's going back.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PendingIntent Try this----

```
 // Use TaskStackBuilder to build the back stack and get the PendingIntent 
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
                    // followed by DetailsActivity itself
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```